# what does @ do in an elements id tag javascript/php and how can i reference this element

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Junior dev working on a website and got thrown by how to reference this element

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="@id-name">Name</label>
                  <input id="@id-name" class="form-control" name="name" required type="text" max-length="70" value="{{$userBot->name ?? null}}">
</div>
```

I was adding the maximum length cap and wanted to create an alert when this limit was reached. I was expecting the solution to look something like this

```
$( '#@id-name' ).on('input', function() {
                                    if ($(this).val().length>70) {
                                        alert('you have reached the maximum characters for bot name');
                                    }
                                });
```

but, not entirely to my surprise, this doesn't seem to be able to get the element to reference, and I tried some variations between jquery and javascript and different "" positionings to no success. I know the site uses php, my assumption is this is a part of that language (php isn't my area of expertise, my role is mostly ux integrations like this alert)

I'm curious how more experienced developers would create a reference to an element with an @ in the id.

Comment: I can't speak for PHP, but there's nothing special about `@` in an `id` in HTML, JavaScript, or jQuery. It's just another character. (It would be a pain to select with a CSS selector, which could be relevant, but...)

Comment: This notation has nothing to do with native PHP.

Comment: Personally, I'd look at the *rendered* html to see if that's actually in the id, or if a pre-processor has replaced it with a variable.

Comment: You should also (**always**) look in the console for errors, `$("#@id-name")` gives error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #@id-name`   https://jsfiddle.net/st6bk250/

Comment: If you do actually have `<input id="@id-name"...` then you can reference it with `$("#\\@id-name")` https://jsfiddle.net/st6bk250/1/

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  *To use any of the meta-characters ( such as* `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^\`{|}~` *) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with[sic] two backslashes: \\\.*